# Cannot find symbol after svn update

Tags: java, maven, svn

Sometimes, if the other developers change/add a bunch of classes in the system and when I click "update to the latest", I got lots of ".... cannot be resolved to a type" or ".... cannot be resolved".

In order to solve this problem, I am trying to update with dependencies with `mvn dependency:resolve` command and I update maven project(with force update). Sometimes, it helps.

When it does not help, I remove the whole local repository and making an update again. Sometimes, it helps also.

However, I know that what I am doing until now is just a brute force. I want to approach the problem more professionally.

What is the best approach when I get "cannot find symbol" error after "update project to head" with svn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is hard to tell the sure shot fix for your issue unless we happen to see more details. 
But to give you one hint,

> just make sure that the Maven is reading the same Java version as what
>   is declared in your pom.xml for the project where you face "cannot
>   find symbol".

Also if you are using eclipse plugins m2e it better at times to run mentioned set of commands in place of  `maven clean install` ,as eclipse loses track of the class files and thinks some of them are undefined.

As a solution you may use following command at the command line instead:

```
mvn eclipse:clean
mvn clean install
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Comment: I just wanted to be sure that what I am doing until right now is the correct approach or not.

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Comment: Yes. Eclipse + Subclipse + Maven

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the company, m2e is used but when I run the commands, I am always using the command line. Does it make any difference if I use command line instead of m2e plugin? I mean if I use command line, is it possible that there is a synronization problem between eclipse and my source code?

Comment: At times eclipse fails to sync the latest maven retrieved code because of its local file history